# Can I perform such an action with cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I need to give my images an extension, depending on their type and also create a completely new name for them. Can I get the extension before I send the file to the server?
`$_POST['image']` is a URL of an image. `$new_name` is supposed to be added while running the switch.

```
$image = $_POST['image'];

$ch = curl_init($image);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$imagedata = curl_exec($ch);

list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($filename);

switch ($type) {
   case 1: ....... //Give the filename a .gif extension and so on for every filetype
}

$fp = fopen('../images/' . $new_name, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

**!FOUND ANSWER! (sorry if I'm answering my own question wrong (in means of simply "editing" the question), comment on how to do it correctly, if I'm wrong ;)**

I simply need to run the cURL function 2 times, but with different names. The first one simply gets me the info about the file, and the second one saves it wit the `$new_name`

> $image = $_POST['image'];
>
> $ch = curl_init($image); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
>   $imagedata = curl_exec($ch); $info = curl_getinfo($ch,
>   CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE); curl_close($ch);
>
> if($info == "image/jpeg") //Running a code that will give the image an
>   appropriate extension...
>
> $cf = curl_init($image); $fp = fopen('../images/' . "image.jpg",
>   'wb'); curl_setopt($cf, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); curl_exec($cf);
>   curl_close($cf); fclose($fp);

Comment: use [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) to get the type

Comment: but can such structure be applied?

Comment: sorry, no idea what your asking there

Comment: I mean running a code in the middle of a cURL.